# How to implement recipes in mongodb (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, api, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I wanted to create a cocktail API based on a nodejs server with mongoose db background. The API would return cocktails with a recipe
I have a working prototype with schemes cocktails, users and ingredients. 
My question is how do I implement the quantities of ingredients? If I eg. would want to use 2cl of an ingredient or 1 tablespoon, how would I implement this in my schemes?

cocktailschema

```
const schema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    recipe: {type: String, required: true },
    ingredients: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Ingredient'
    }],
    creator: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'User'
    },
    createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

userschema

```
const schema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    hash: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    favoriteCocktails:[{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Cocktail"
    }],
    createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

ingredientsschema

```
const schema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    alcoholic: { type: Boolean, required: true },
    description: {type: String, required: false},
    createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

I was thinking of adding a string in the cocktailschema in the ingredients variable. How would I implement this?
Any helping tips on how to do this or improve this are very welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement quantities into for your ingredients, look at the ingredient's schema.

```
const schema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    alcoholic: { type: Boolean, required: true },
    description: {type: String, required: false},
    createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

You already have information with the name, description, alcoholic, created date, etc. By adding a field for quantity, such as `quantity: {type: String, required: false},` you can input your desired information. Alternatively, if you want to have quantity as an integer, you can have two fields: one for quantity (5) and one for quantity type (tablespoons)

**EDIT**

To reduce the number of ingredient models, you could add the information to a nested place on the cocktail schema when putting in ingredients. Like so (Under cocktailschema):

```
ingredients: [{
        ingredient: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Ingredient'}
        quantity: {type: Number, required: false},
        quantityType: {type: String, required: false}
    }],
```

Comment: Using this example, wouldn't there be a lot of ingredients with the same name? In one recipe one would use 2cl of Vodka, in another 4cl. then there would be 2 Vodka ingredients?

Comment: That is valid; I updated my response for another possible solution that takes this into account @JefVandooren

Comment: That looks like the answer I need! Do I need to update the Ingredients scheme too if I would use this?

Comment: Nope, your ingredient schema should be able to stay the same. You would just need to change how you enter the data into cocktailschema :)

Comment: Thanks! really helped a lot!

Comment: Problem when trying to add a cocktail. I entered the following :
`
{
    "name": "Cooled Vodka",
    "recipe": "Vodka and Ice, what's there to do wrong?",
    "ingredients": [
        {
            "ingredient": "5eb8611ebf0d4b0017bf0d47",
            "quantity": "4",
            "quantityType": "pcs"
        },
        {
            "ingredient": "5eb86186bf0d4b0017bf0d48",
            "quantity": "4",
            "quantityType": "cl"
        }
    ],
    "creator": "5eb85eb0bf0d4b0017bf0d46"
}
`
It shows ingredients as an empty array when getting the cocktail

Comment: @JefVandooren Did you populate https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate the field?

Comment: yes, in my service I populate the ingredients like this

        `.populate('ingredients', 'name alcoholic')`

then I populate the creator of the cocktail like this

        `.populate('creator', 'username')`

lastly I use select

        `.select('name recipe ingredients creator');`

creator works, ingredients returns an empty array

Comment: I asked [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61778955/sending-array-of-data-in-object-to-api-results-in-empty-array-in-object) on Stack Overflow since my original question was answered